# List Item CSS pseudo shape dynamic height with menu height

Tags: html, css, less

**I am trying to create a menu which will show a pseudo polygon to show the arrow for the selected menu item, I am facing with two challenges**

1. First How to make the dynamic height of the `::after` pseudo shape, whenever the menu/link item font size or height changes it need to adjust
2. Second - How to show the arrow/the `::after pseudo arrow` ONLY for the active or clicked menu

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, san-sarif;
  color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

:root {
  --myMenuColor: silver;
}

.base-container {
  display: flex;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 4;
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: var(--myMenuColor);
  border: 1px solid var(--myMenuColor);
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.arrow_box::after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box::after {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-width: 19px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: var(--myMenuColor);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing Flex box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="base-container">

    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="arrow_box">
        <h1 class="logo">First Menu</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow_box">
        <h1 class="logo">Second Menu</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow_box">
        <h1 class="logo">Third Menu</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To have a responsive 'arrow' height/width, you could change from `border-width` to `padding`. Because you need to use `percentages` to set size relative to parent and `border-width` does not support `percentages` but `padding` does.

So for example `padding:10%` would mean that it will be `20%` of `arrow_box` height and width.

2. To set it only on `active` and/or `clicked` elements, you need to use `javaScript/jQuery` to toggle classes but since you didn't tag `javaScript` in your question, i made you and example with `:hover`.

   .arrow_box:hover:after { 
       /* add styles here */
   }

When you will have an `.active` class, you can use `.arrow-box.active:after {}`

See below

```css
:root{
--myMenuColor: silver;
}

.base-container
{
    display: flex;

}

.main-content{
    flex:4;
}

.menu-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: var(--myMenuColor);
    border: 1px solid var(--myMenuColor);
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    z-index:2;

}
.arrow_box::after{
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(-100%,-50%);
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    padding:10%;
    background: var(--myMenuColor);
    transition:0.3s ease-out;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
.arrow_box:hover:after { /* arrow_box.active:after */
  opacity:1;
  transform:translate(0,-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="base-container">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="arrow_box">
      <h1 class="logo">First Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow_box">
      <h1 class="logo">Second Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow_box">
      <h1 class="logo">Third Menu</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</div>
```